# .toggle(true) throw null in $(document).ready(function())

Tags: asp.net, jquery, toggle

I am toggling row siblings. I wrote .toggle(true) when document ready. see below picture. I think row sibling are not availble before this function calls.

[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

       $('tr[@class^=RegText]').hide().children('td');

        list_Visible_Ids = [];
        var idsString, idsArray;

        idsString = $('#myVisibleRows').val();
        idsArray = idsString.split(',');

        $.each(idsArray, function() {
            if (this != "") {
                $(this).siblings('.RegText').toggle(true);
                list_Visible_Ids[this] = 1;
            }
        });
```

[image]

[image]

**How to resolve this? why sliblings are not avaible in when document is ready?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your posted code doesn't match the debugger code, your code has this, which is (almost!) correct:

```
$(this).siblings('.RegText').toggle(true);
```

The debugger has this, which is incorrect:

```
$(this).siblings(('.RegText').toggle(true));
```

You need to update whatever you're actually debugging to that code without the extra parenthesis, otherwise you're going to get some pretty funky behavior there.

[Also you need a `#`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) in there since your debugger shows you're not storing the hash mark in the array, which is perfectly fine.  You're currently calling `$("row10")` (which looks for `<row10>` elements), but what you need is `$("#row10")` (which looks for `id="row10"` elements), so adjust your call like this:

```
$('#' + this).siblings('.RegText').toggle(true);
```

Comment: I works good for me. Thanks Nick. But I am loosing .css (font mismatch).

Why font is missing?